# Chef recipe gives error as undefined method 'split'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-recipe

I am using this code in my Chef recipe. It works fine with all the other existing servers, however it doesn't work well with my new server:

```
user_array = node
node['user']['user_array_node_attr'].split("/").each do |hash_key|
  user_array = user_array.send(:[], hash_key)
end
```

It returns an error:

```
FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any value in

```
node['user']['user_array_node_attr'] #=> nil
```

You can check for the presence

```
node['user']['user_array_node_attr'].present? && node['user']['user_array_node_attr'].split("/").each do |hash_key|
 user_array = user_array.send(:[], hash_key)
end
```

Comment: You can eliminate `.present?` and it will work nearly the same. Actually better, as `.present?` will evaluate to false on an empty string, and here (I think) you want that to evaluate to true to assign an empty array to `user_array` in that instance.

Comment: `present?` will still result in the same error if `['user_array_node_attr']` doesn't exist or returns nil.